# Where can I get these two jars - db2jcc4_license_cu and db2jcc4_license_cisuz?

Tags: db2, driver

I am trying to configure my project with IBM WAS 8.5.5.12 with J.D.K 1.8 and need type 4 driver for connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about DB2 for z/OS.

Then the answer can be found [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21413734). The important parts:

> The db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar file is included in all DB2 Connect server editions including DB2 Connect Personal Edition. The license is also part the IBM Database Enterprise Developer Edition. If you already have one of these products, then please use the license file from the DB2 Connect Activation CD. If you have a Passport Advantage account, then remember to download the activation key from Passport Advantage for the DB2 Connect edition that you have purchased.
>
> The db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar file is located in the /db2/license directory of the activation CD or activation file downloaded from Passport Advantage.

And:

> **I don't have a DB2 Connect product. Now what do I do?**
>
> If you do not have the file, then you must purchase a DB2 Connect product so that you may license the JDBC driver to connect to a mainframe.

Probably your DB2 administrators can provide you with the files...

Comment: Hello peit , i am looking for db2jcc4_license_cisuz.jar instead of db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar.
Also is it available as a open source or do i have to buy the full product.